# how to linkage with dropbox in window programming

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, window, dropbox

I'd like to make MFC program that connecting with Dropbox. 
So I found Dropbox api but looks like can't use on window.
(https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore)

How to use Dropbox api on window ?

Could you tell me information related this topic ?

Or

Anyone who has developed similar to this program ?

My system environment is as follow :

OS : window 7 32bit

develop tool : visual studio 2008

Comment: So use Python or JavaScript SDK. Where is your problem?

Comment: this program must developed by C++.

Answer (score 2):

Dropbox's Core API supports a RESTful API over HTTPS which you can use to directly interact with Dropbox.

[Dropbox Core API documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs)

Comment: Thank you. I'll be back after reviewing :D